# updating an entity in dynamics crm bug creates a new related entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have 2 related entities lets say A and B in a 1:1 relationship. I m using in my Repository an OrganizationService named service.

I have a method that calls other methods and its main role is to update entities A n B.

```
var deactivate = DeactivateA(guidOfA);
//System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
var updateA=UpdateA(guidOfA)
....do some computations here...
service.Update(B)
```

If I run this code without Thread.Sleep not only updates current B object but also generates a new object of B.If  I uncomment Thread.Sleep(5000) then it works normally .It just updates the current B object without generating a new one. Below there are my 2 methods

DeactivateA changes A status from Active to Inactive

```
reqState = new SetStateRequest();
reqState.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("hast_assetrequest", guidId);
reqState.State = new OptionSetValue(1);
reqState.Status = new OptionSetValue(2);
respState =service.Execute(reqState) as SetStateResponse;
```

UpdateA changes some of the values of A properties after its deactivation

```
//get A in order to updated it
var A = new A() { Id = guidId, AId = guidId};
A.propertyA= some value;
//similar actions
service.Update(A);
```

I suspect that service.Execute and service.Update does not cooperate promptly.

Comment: Can you safely rule out that there are no (asynchronous) Plugin Steps or Workflows registered on UPDATE and/or SETSTATE? Usually unexpected effects like this result from registering Plugin Steps to fire on all attributes. Also look out for Business Rules registered to fire on Entity (not only on an specific Form).

Comment: Deactivate all plugins, workflows and business rules and see if it happens again (most likely, it won't)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.If there are workflows or business rules then why if I pause the execution with System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); after the status deactivation, it works as expected?

Comment: records don't get created by themselves...

Comment: You were right,it was a workflow that run on the background! The workflow detects a combination of status update and status reason update of A in order to create a new B.So when I use a pause of 5 sec the workflow runs but the status reason update is not fulfilled,so it does not create a new B object.

Comment: @Filburt would you provide an answer, since this problem was solved by your suggestion so that others dont need to bother helping out here? ;)

Comment: @nozzleman I voted to close since the described problem could not be reproduced once the responsible component was identified. If you think it should stay, feel free to create an answer from my comment.